# PHP developer to .net development

Tags: .net, php

I know it is not a programming related,

I am in PHP Development for last 2 years, now will it be possible(how hard) or advisale for me to shift to .net Development.

any help ?

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ramp Up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/rampup/default.aspx) is a microsoft site that has training based upon prior experience.  For example, you can take training for php developers, where they use php constructs as analogies for things you are learning.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible.  I've worked in both, and while I find things about both platforms that I prefer over the other, I don't think it's terribly hard to learn one system having already worked on the other.

For me it was no harder than any other time I've learned a new language.

Answer (score 0):

If you understand the programming semantics, picking up on another language or technology should just be a matter of learning that particular language's syntax.  Of course, there are always exceptions.  For instance, you may do something in one particular way in PHP or C#, whereas there is an alternate, "pythonic" way to do it.  But once you grok the core programming fundamentals, those should be relatively trivial to pick up.  If you are a native PHP developer, you should have a relatively small learning curve going to something like C#.  The syntax of the two languages are pretty darn close.  I initially started developing in PHP and eventually switched to .NET with a slight learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's more than just possible. It's not a secret that if you know one language it will only be simpler to study another one. Technologies that are used in different languages are similar and it'll certainly help you.